# MySQL FULLTEXT search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How do you add a column to a fulltext search in MySQL to indicate which words were included in the search?

Answer (score 2):

You mean query or index definition? 
For query it would be something like this:

```
WHERE 
  MATCH (colA, colB) AGAINST ('+words* +you* +search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The SELECT statement is really where I need the guidance.  For example, if this is the query:

select AlbumID, Title from Albums
where match(AlbumDesc)
against('albums')
union
select AlbumID, Title from Albums
where match(AlbumDesc)
against('albums' with query expansion)
union
select AlbumID, Title from Albums
where match(AlbumDesc)
against('studio')
union
select AlbumID, Title from Albums
where match(AlbumDesc)
against('studio' with query expansion);

how do I display the words used for the query (i.e. 'album' and 'studio')?

Comment: If you want to know, which word does the result fit, then you can always add this word to the result, ie: 

select AlbumID, Title, 'albums' as SearchWord
from Albums 
where match(AlbumDesc) against('albums') 

and do the same with other queries.

Answer (score 2):

Michal got the query syntax down, to create a full text index to assist this search use

```
Create FULLTEXT Index Test ON Table1(ColumnName1)
```

Much more at [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score -3):

Use the following command

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name"
ADD INDEX " INDEX_NAME " (COLUMN_NAME)
```

Comment: -1 I think this is only useful for a standard search not the full-text search the questioner desires (i.e. search for any word or words within the field)